# Exc bad access in table view - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array that fill when user click search button. If there is no data for that response, server return empty response and therefore here is an empty array. I wonder, why when i fire fake request it return me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xa)`.

It point to:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (_arrValues.count > 0)
        return self.arrValues.count;

    return 0;
}
```

To line:

```
if (_arrValues.count > 0)
```

In `viewDidLoad` I did allocate an array like that:

```
_arrValues   = @[];
```

So, I cant understand why this occurs. Any suggestions?
In debugger it simply prints an array memory and ISA pointer, obviously there is no data if user search fake request that return nothing.

From debug panel:

[image]

When I update my server part like that (remove response and always create an empty array) problem is disappeared. Probably there is an issue in my request/mapping part:

```
  //    _arrValues = [eventsMgr getEventsFromResponse:x];
        _arrValues = @[];
```

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: Probably `_arrValues` is `nil` at some time. You don't need the check for zero, just return `return self.arrValues.count;`.

Comment: @Droppy what exaclty should i show?

Comment: @vadian i did check for if (_arrValues) it still crash ..

Comment: I want to see the stacktrace.

Comment: just return `return self.arrValues.count` ..

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 it was. It was pointing me to that line,

Comment: add code related to call to server and storing response to array@EvgeniyKleban

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I would imagine the issue is that this object (that implements `UITableviewDatasource`) has been released.  You will need to show how this object is managed.

Comment: @RonakChaniyara it simply parsing and mapping response that involve a lot of code.

Comment: after initial table load, _arrValues getting deallocated that can be the case@EvgeniyKleban

Comment: @RonakChaniyara okay thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_arrValues count];
}
```

Comment: @Droppy it was return [_arrValues count]; before i encounter error. Also i wonder, why there is no crash when it empty when table first load, so return [_arrValues count]; work.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban That's because "sending a message" to a `nil` Objective-C is a "no-op" and in this case it will return `0`, which is ideal.  Your error is elsewhere, however as there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Droppy where should i look?

Comment: I want to see the stacktrace.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Why have you accepted this answer?  We all know this isn't the real reason for the exception you were getting.